# Failed in parallel Running with inequal input channel in Nextflow

Tags: parallel-processing, nextflow

I am trying to run parallel for three files in my directory with 2 processes:

- `READ`:  get input files `metadata_*.txt` simultaneously with the another inequal input channel, `echo` them, and export the output file for the next process.
- `READ_AGAIN`: Just do it again.

My working directory is:

```
.
├── metadata_1.txt
├── metadata_2.txt
├── metadata_3.txt
└── para.nf

0 directories, 4 files
```

This is my strategy:
[image]

I tried to do it by myself (`para.nf`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

params.file = "$PWD/metadata_*.txt"

process READ{

    debug true

    input:
    val a
    path file, stageAs: '*'

    output:
    path file

    """
    echo $a
    echo $file
    """
}

process READ_AGAIN{

    debug true

    input:
    val a
    path file_read

    """
    echo $a
    echo $file_read
    """
}

workflow{
    text = Channel.of('hello')                             # Channel has 1 input length
    input = Channel.fromPath(params.file)                  # Channel has 3 input length
    out_read = READ(text, input.flatten())
    READ_AGAIN(text, out_read)
}
```

And it is just run one time:

```
$ nextflow run para.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.2
Launching `para.nf` [distraught_poisson] DSL2 - revision: 87a499da7a
executor >  local (2)
[5b/bf9022] process > READ (1)       [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[ae/79a005] process > READ_AGAIN (1) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
hello
metadata_3.txt

hello
metadata_3.txt
```

According to [multiple input channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-channels), I already know if 2 different input channels have disparate input lengths, Nextflow will parallel run the smallest input length (one, in my case).

I really need some help to do my strategy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the [`Channel.of`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#of) factory method produces a [Queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel), but what you want is a [Value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) which can be bound to a single value and read an unlimited number of times. You could use the [`Channel.value`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value) method for this:

```
workflow {

    text = Channel.value('hello')
    ...
}
```

But you could also use a simple String instead. This works because simple values (e.g. strings, files, etc) are implicitly converted to value channels when the process is invoked:

```
workflow {

    text = 'hello'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful information about the type of channels. But my text channel presents the complicated output of another channel.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out my answer for my case is using [tuple input](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-tuple) and [combine operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

params.file = "$PWD/metadata_*.txt"

process READ{

    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(a), path(file, stageAs: '*')

    output:
    path file

    """
    echo $a
    echo $file
    """
}

process READ_AGAIN{

    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(a), path(file_read)

    """
    echo 'read again'
    echo $file_read
    """
}

workflow{
    text = Channel.of('hello')
    input = Channel.fromPath(params.file)

    
    out_read = READ(text.combine(input))
    READ_AGAIN(text.combine(out_read))
}
```